# Can a constant be a moment generating function of a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I need to disprove that there exists a random variable $X$ such that its MGF is $M_X(t)=e$. Not sure how to approach this...

Comment: Is $e$ the natural base $2.7\ldots$ or a variable representing some constant?

Comment: e is the natural number

Comment: I think the answer to the literal question in the title is “yes,” but there is only one constant that can be a MGF and $e$ isn’t it.

Comment: Which random variable is it? 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that we have a random varible $\mathbf{X}$ and denote its probability distribution $f(x)$, for simplicity assume that this is a real random variable in one dimension,but any higher dimension euclidean space would also do the trick.

Now assume that the moment generating function is constant thus $M_X(t) = c$.
From the definition of $M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{t\mathbf{X}}]$ we note that for $t= 0$ it holds :

$$M_X(0) = \mathbb{E}[e^{0 \cdot \mathbf{X}}] = \mathbb{E}[1] = 1$$

Now since we assumed that $M_X(t) $ is constant, it must be equal to one everywhere. Now we take the derivative of moment generating function, and if I understood the Leibniz integration rule correctly the derivative is:

$$M_X^{'}(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} t e^{tx}f(x) \mathrm{d}x = t M_X(t)$$

But since the MGF ( moment-generating function ) is constant, this would have to be zero for all t, since this is not true, it can not be true that there exists a random variable whose MGF is constant

Comment: I think you need to justify that differentiation and (improper) integration can be interchanged. I believe Leibniz rule is for proper integration of continuous function. If $X$ is not continuous, we may not even have a density function.

Comment: Hello @ashpool , you are most likely right, but this has been answered during my bachelor thesis days, and given my transition to non-academic profession, today this mathematics baffles me as much as any random reader. Feel free to correct any mistakes

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Note that 
$$
M_{X}(0)=Ee^{0\cdot X}=E(1)=1.
$$

Comment: So for any MGF, its value at $0$ must be $1$?

Comment: Yes that is the case